# Java: Adding Double.MIN_NORMAL to a double doesn't change the number

Tags: java, double, double-precision, epsilon

I thought that MIN_NORMAL was a value that you could add to a "normal" double and the number will change. E.g. add Double.MIN_NORMAL to 0.1d and you get a value different from 0.1d, however my understanding is wrong:

```
public static void test(double val) {
    if (val == (val - Double.MIN_NORMAL*1e50d))
        System.out.printf("val == (val - Double.MIN_NORMAL*1e50d) for val=%.20f\n", val);
    else
        System.out.printf("val != (val - Double.MIN_NORMAL*1e50d) for val=%.20f\n", val);
}
```

Which produces:

```
test(0.0d);
> val != (val - Double.MIN_NORMAL*1e50d) for val=0.00000000000000000000

test(1.0d);
> val == (val - Double.MIN_NORMAL*1e50d) for val=1.00000000000000000000

test(0.1d);
> val == (val - Double.MIN_NORMAL*1e50d) for val=0.10000000000000000000
```

Somebody pls explain what's going against my logic here, that even if I add MIN_NORMAL times 1e50d, I still get the same number.

I checked binary representations and 1 * Double.MIN_NORMAL is different from 2 * Double.MIN_NORMAL, but subtracting those from anything except zero does not change the original number.

Comment: [Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#MIN_NORMAL) clearly define it as 2 to the power of `-1022`.  So, your `1e50d` is nothing in comparison.

Comment: `MIN_NORMAL` is guaranteed to have an effect when added/subtracted from `0`, but you can't rely on it having an effect otherwise. In particular, it is *not* going to do anything to comparatively gigantic numbers like `1.0` or `0.1`.

Comment: It is not the case that subtracting Double.MIN_NORMAL from anything except 0 does not change the original value. Try 1e-300.

Comment: For some reason I was thinking, that MIN_NORMAL was the minimal distance between 2 representable values, when the whole part is >0. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MIN_NORMAL` is, as the Javadoc says, only the smallest normalized `double` value. But that doesn't mean it is something like `1` for `int`s: For floating-point point values, there simply is **no** standard "eps" you can add to change to the next representable value -- the "eps" always depends on the exponent of the given floating-point value. That's why they're called **floating** points, in the end :)

However, Java 1.6+ provides [`Math.nextAfter()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#nextAfter%28double,%20double%29) which returns, for any given `double`, the next or previous representable `double`.

On older Java versions, you can always mess around with `Double.doubleToLongBits()`, incrementing or decrementing its result, and converting back by `Double.longBitsToDouble()`; this gets you the next or previous representable `double` value -- *in most cases*: there are a few special cases (NaN, infinite values), so this is not recommended to floating-point newbies :)

Comment: Thanks for Math.nextAfter(), I'm changing the accepted answer!

Answer (score 2):

Double has a limited precision. MIN_NORMAL is 2e-1022.  It will be dropped unless the number you add it to is also in the ballpark of 2e-1000.